# Interpolation for 3 values

Tags: math, interpolation, algebra

I'm not a mathematical genie, so my question is poor defined. I have a float value which correlates to three integers. Here is an example:

```
0.5 = { 1000, 984, 880 }
6   = { 1000, 949, 664 }
10  = { 999, 976, 801 }
```

Now let's say i have three new values like 900, 920, 752. How can i interpolate between those records and find the value for example maybe "4.53413424"?

Thank you for reading and all comments.

Comment: Think of your triplets as points in 3D space. Your info can be thought of as mapping times (e.g. 0.5, 6 or 10) to points in space. Now you pick a new point in space (e.g. `(900, 920, 752)`) and wish to know at what time your curve passes through that point. Unfortunately, there are an infinite number of curves that could pass through your given data at the given times. Those curves may or may not happen to also pass through `(900, 920, 752)`. So without more information (to specify which curve we are talking about) there is no single answer to your question.

Comment: The "curve" you talking about is maybe linear? Sorry i have no background to express this more correct.
I thought i can user Apache Commons Math to solve this task. But so far i don't know some terms of "what i should do" i can't find the specific content like code examples.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

You could (perhaps) think of your initial data as the definition of a linear function that maps triples (or 3D points) to numbers. Here is how to proceed:

1. Let `M` be the matrix whose columns are the triples you have

   ```
   [1000 1000 999
     984  949 976
     880  664 801]
   ```
2. Let `invM` be the inverse of `M`. In this case:

   ```
   [112085/1218744 -1912/16927 27949/1218744
      8837/152343  -1085/16927   877/152343
    -22718/152343   3000/16927 -4375/152343]
   ```
3. Now compute the product `[0.5 6 10]` times `invM`. The result is the triple:

   ```
    [-891481/812496 22534/16927 -195953/812496]
   ```
4. Finally, for every triple `(x, y, z)` compute the value it maps to as

   ```
    -891481/812496 * x + 22534/16927 * y -195953/812496 * z
   ```

this is the number you were looking for (under a linear extension of you data)